# Python - function arguments not working

Tags: python, function, tkinter, ctypes

I am making this small program, where the user can input the x and y axis of the screen where they wish to move the mouse to, and how many time they would like to click on that pixel.

**My problem** is when I try to put the variables into this function, the arguments apparently cannot be converted? The *SetCurPos()* is the problem, it will take SetCurPos(x,y), but I receive the error:

```
    File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ManipulationTools.py", line 13, in click
        SetCursorPos(x,y)
    ArgumentError: argument 1: : Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

My Code:

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import time
    import ctypes
    #from MoveCursor import click

    class ManipulationTools():

    ##############FUNCTIONS###################################
        def click(x,y, numclicks):
            SetCursorPos = ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos
            mouse_event = ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event

            SetCursorPos(x,y)
            E1.DELETE(0, END)
            E2.DELETE(0, END)
            E3.DELETE(0, END)

            for i in xrange(numclicks):
                mouse_event(2,0,0,0,0)
                mouse_event(4,0,0,0,0)



    #############END FUNCTIONS################################   
        root = Tk()

        root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)
        root.minsize(width=400, height=400)

        root.config(bg="black")

        L1 = Label(root,text="Enter the x and y value here:", fg="white", bg="black")
        L1.place(x=20, y=20)
        Lx = Label(root, text="X:",fg="white",bg="black")
        Lx.place(x=170,y=20)
        Ly = Label(root, text="Y:",fg="white",bg="black")
        Ly.place(x=240,y=20)
        Lnum = Label(root, text="Number of Times:",fg="white",bg="black")
        Lnum.place(x=150, y=100)

        E1 = Entry(root, width=5, bg="grey", )
        E1.place(x=190,y=20)
        E2 = Entry(root, width=5, bg="grey",)
        E2.place(x=260,y=20)
        E3 = Entry(root, width=5, bg="grey",)
        E3.place(x=260,y=100)

        a=IntVar(E1.get())
        b=IntVar(E2.get())
        c=IntVar(E3.get())


        con = Button(root, command=click(a,b,c), text="Confirm", bg="white")
        con.place(x=300,y=300)

        root.mainloop()
```

My Traceback error when I click the button to confirm the numbers in the fields entered:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ManipulationTools.py", line 6, in 
        class ManipulationTools():
      File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ManipulationTools.py", line 53, in ManipulationTools
        con = Button(root, command=click(a,b,c), text="Confirm", bg="white")
      File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ManipulationTools.py", line 13, in click
        SetCursorPos(x,y)
    ArgumentError: argument 1: : Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call `####functions####` are actually *methods*, and hence, the first argument they get is always the reference to the instance of their containing class, which commonly is named `self`. You can, however, name that parameter like you want to, which is what happened here:

```
class ManipulationTools():
    def click(x,y, numclicks):
```

`x` is what elsewhere would be called `self`, not the first argument that you give when doing something like

```
tools = ManipulationTools()
tools.click(100,200,1) ## this should actually give you an error -- ManipulationTools.click gets called with 4 arguments (self, 100, 200, 1), but is only defined for 3 (self, y, numclicks)
```

The right thing to do is:

```
class ManipulationTools():
    def click(self, x,y, numclicks):
```

Comment: can't you also use lambda

Comment: not quite sure what you're referring to. So, I'll say: no.